# nconf is not working with NPM start command

Tags: node.js, nconf

I have these two node.js command line commands:

```
 $  NODE_ENV=dev_local npm start --fp data_for_testing/csvfile.csv --mptp map_ivr_itg
 $  NODE_ENV=dev_local node start_script --fp data_for_testing/csvfile.csv --mptp map_ivr_itg
```

I am using nconf the command line and environment variable parser for node.js.

The problem is the command line arguments --fp and --mptp seem to disappear when using npm start.

[image]

Furthermore, as an aside, does any program interpret --fp as a force flag, as NPM is warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command line flags (e.g., `--fp`) are being sent to `npm` and not the script that results from running `npm start`. To send them to the resulting script as arguments, [first send `--` by itself as an argument](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start). That indicates that the remaining arguments are for the resulting script and not for `npm` itself.

```
npm start -- --fp ...
```

Comment: Since `npm start` doesn't necessarily map to a single command but could instead be a pipeline of commands, multiple commands run in sequence, multiple commands connected via `&&` and/or `||` operators, etc., passing arguments has to be handled in a funky way. Consider using environment variables or configuration files for something more robust.